# Get projection matrix of lda in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, projection, eigenvector, linear-discriminant

I need to get the projection matrix from lda, which has been supplied the train data, so that I can use that to project the train data in the lda space.

I have done the following :

```
def get_projection(features,label):

    transformer = LDA(store_covariance=True)
    transformer.fit_transform(features,label)   
    cov_mat = transformer.covariance_

    return cov_mat
```

I have then extracted the eigen vectors of the covariance matrix. But that doesn't seem to give correct solution. Even the .scalings_ attribute doesn't seem to be helpful.
Kindly help me find the projection matrix from this method, so that I can apply it on test data, which don't have labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the transformer directly on test data by `transformer.transform(test_data)`. See [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.lda.LDA.html#sklearn.lda.LDA.transform) of LDA here.

Note: LDA has been deprecated and now its recommended to use [LinearDiscriminantAnalysis](http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis).

Comment: Can you please tell me which attribute gives the projection matrix?

Comment: The tranform() method internally uses dot product between the data and the `scalings_` to find the projection. Since you are using default LDA, you also need to subtract the means of the data before dot product. See the [source here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/discriminant_analysis.py#L482)